# Join Registers in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, i have 2 tables:

Table Countries:

```
id Names_countries   
------------------   
0  United States
```

Table Cities

```
id Names_cities
---------------
0  Los Angeles
```

How can i create this ?

New table

```
all registers
-------------
United States
Los Angeles
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are are asking?  How to create tables?  How to query them?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator

Comment: [`SELECT Names_countries AS \`all registers\` FROM Countries UNION ALL SELECT Names_cities FROM Cities`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a268e/1/0)?

Comment: Do you want to create a new table and fill it, or just select from the two? Do you want only the cities of a certain country? If so, then why do you need the country as well, because you already know, what country you want the cities from?

I think you have to specify your question. If we do not know, what you are trying to **achieve**, you might not get the answers you **want**.

Comment: It's UNION ALL. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the union operator

So:

```
SELECT Names_countries all_registers FROM Countries
UNION
SELECT names_cities FROM Cities
```

Answer (score 0):

See this 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89ffd/3

```
select Names_countries from Countries
UNION
select Names_cities from Cities
```